# Вопрос по классу ManualRestEvent

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. Кто мене может объяснить назначение класса ManualRestEvent? Меня не понятно, что делают функции:

1. Set()
2. WaitOn()
3. Reset()

Answer (score 2):

[ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) позволяет потокам взаимодействовать друг с другом путем передачи сигналов. Обычно это взаимодействие касается задачи, которую один поток должен завершить до того, как другой продолжит работу.

> Когда поток начинает работу, которая
> должна быть завершена до продолжения
> работы других потоков, он вызывает
> метод **Reset** для того, чтобы поместить
> ManualResetEvent в несигнальное
> состояние. Этот поток можно понимать
> как контролирующий ManualResetEvent.
> Потоки, которые вызывают метод **WaitOne**
> в ManualResetEvent, будут
> заблокированы, ожидая сигнала. Когда
> контролирующий поток завершит работу,
> он вызовет метод **Set** для сообщения о
> том, что ожидающие потоки могут
> продолжить работу. Все ожидающие
> потоки освобождаются.

проще говоря, если мы вызвали **WaitOne**, поток прекратит работу до того момента, пока не будет вызван метод **Set** этого же объекта. **Reset** "взводит" все WaitOne заново.

является кросс-процессорным

ссылки:

- [Signaling with Event Wait Handles](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Signaling_with_Event_Wait_Handles)
- [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx)

Reset() - Задает несигнальное состояние события, вызывая блокирование потоков.

Set() - Задает сигнальное состояние события, позволяя одному или нескольким ожидающим потокам продолжить.

WaitOne() - Блокирует текущий поток до получения сигнала объектом WaitHandle.